# Javascript, deep extend

Tags: javascript

So I have an object I'm trynig to deep extend into - right now the extend function works if the lowest level is just an array, So it looks like this :

```
  function(base, next) {
      var dataEntry = base.filter(function(it) {
            return it.module === next.module;
          })[0];
          if (dataEntry) {
            var diff = next.customUrl.filter(function(it) {
              return dataEntry.customUrl.indexOf(it) === -1;
            });
                dataEntry.customUrl = dataEntry.customUrl.concat(diff).sort();
                //_.extend(dataEntry, next);
          } else {
            base.push(next);
        }
    }
```

And this works if the object looks like :

```
 [
 {"name" : "one", "test" : ["1","2"]},
 {"name" : "two", "test" : ["1","2"]}
 ]
```

However some things had to change and now the object looks like this :

```
  [
 {"name" : "one", "test" : [{"random1" : true},{"random2" :  false}] },
 {"name" : "two", "test" : [{"random3" : true},{"random4" :  false}]}
 ]
```

Where the keys in the array is now an array of objects, and the objects keys are random. So If there was an object with the same key - replace the value (unless its the same, otherwise push a new object inside of there.

So for that object above I would pass this to merge into it for example:

```
{"name" : "one", "test" : [{"random2" :  true}]}
```

So that would change the value of random2 to true, or something like this

```
{"name" : "one", "test" : [{"random18" : true}] }
```

where that would push in random 18 like so :

```
[
 {"name" : "one", "test" : [{"random1" : true},{"random2" :  false},{"random18" : true}] },
 {"name" : "two", "test" : [{"random3" : true},{"random4" :  false}]}
 ]
```

Unsure how to traverse deeper and merge. Thanks for reading!!

Edit : first stab at it -

```
  function(base, next) {
      var dataEntry = base.filter(function(it) {
            return it.module === next.module;
          })[0];
          if (dataEntry) {
                var allTags = [];
                allTags.push.apply(allTags, dataEntry.customUrl);
                allTags.push.apply(allTags, next.customUrl);

                dataEntry.customUrl = allTags;

          } else {
            base.push(next);
        }
    }
```

Does not work because it does not cover over objects if they are the same, just pushes into array.

Comment: @djechlin ofcourse, where I am unsure is how you check the dynmic keys in the object array against each other and have them overrite the value if they are the same, else push in

Comment: are you supposed to use jQuery?

Comment: @TimHallyburton can use whatever needs to be used.

Comment: all right. Have posted a possible solution for you.

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/p08ayvv8/ 
this fiddle shows you how jQuery can deal with (deep) extending objects.
See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.extend/ for a detailed explaination.

 It is mentionable though that when preforming the second extension jQuery will prepend the old value of test to the array, thats why I added

```
o1.test = o1.test[0];
```